# WCF transaction disappearing between client and server

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, trace

I have a WCF service. I have a client that makes asynchronous calls to the service.
I have 45 test records. The client gets each record from the database and calls the wcf service asynchronously.

When I test each record individually, the service processes the records as expected. However when I pass all 45 at the same time (45 calls made one after the other in a foreach loop) 1 record never makes it to the service. The same record, every time does not make it to the service.

I've enabled trace logging on both the client and the server side, and on the client side I can see the missing message making the call to the server.
On the server trace logs I can see no sign of this record.

Anyone any ideas why/what might be happening? Any suggestions of further steps to try and get to the bottom of it?

I thought it might be a memory issue as some of the records would be large (they contain excel data). However on passing in a subset with the largest records, they all process correctly and none go missing!

Thanks in advance for help or suggestions.

Comment: if you can see the message on client side, which is the response of request? is there any response or error?

Comment: I hadn't even noticed the responses as when I viewed they hadn't yet received a response. After your question I checked again and noticed a timeout response. I've updated the SendTimeout on the binding and so far all 46 are sending and being processed ok. As it was intermittent (well fairly consistent today but was intermitted before this) I'm going to see if this fixed it by keeping an eye on it. Thank you